# fop pdf blank even pages

Tags: pdf, apache-fop

I'm generating PDF using Apache FOP. I have a requirement to display the content only in Odd pages and leave the Even pages blank. I managed to do this earlier with FOP 0.95 and below like this, by setting the margin-top of the "region-body" to the full height of the page.

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster-Even" page-height="279mm" page-width="216mm" margin-left="12mm" margin-top="0mm" margin-bottom="0mm">
  <fo:region-body margin-top="279mm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

Recently I updated FOP version to 1.1 to support some additional features. Now with FOP 1.1, the above logic does not work.  Appreciate if someone could help me with a suggestion to make my text appear only on odd pages.
Please note, my data is sent as an xml and I use as xsl to convert it to an fo file.